# Make status bar opaque programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

There are 2 Fragments of the Activity. When the first Fragment is visible, I want the status bar to be translucent (no Toolbar here). That works as expected.

But when I switch over to the second Fragment, I want the status bar to be opaque. And the Toolbar should be drawn below the status bar. I want these changes to be done programmatically because I can't do it in the Activity XML.

So far I've tried the following code. But this doesn't work.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        view.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_LAYOUT_FLAGS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }
```

This is the screen I'm getting:

[image: incorrect_behaviour]

But I want the status bar to have primaryDark colour and the Toolbar to appear below it.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.blogspot.smarphy.pierecipe">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_homey"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RecipesCardsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipes_cards"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.OpaqueStatus" />

        <service android:name=".Services.HomeCardsNetworkService" />
        <service android:name=".Services.SearchCardsNetworkService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you correctly.

You want to switch from fullscreen to normal when you switch from fragment 1 to 2.

You probably have this on your activity if not use this

```
android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
```

In fragment 2 you can use this to setup non-fullscreen mode.
@Nullable

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        ....
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        ....
    }
```

You should clear fullscreen flag when adding non-fullscreen.

Info: 
*The translucent* status bar was introduced in **API level 19**.

Comment: @Anand Can you update your question with code from manifest about your activity?

Comment: Edited, please check

Comment: @Anand are you how are you setting fullscreen on fragment one? Cause none of the activities has fullscreen theme on.

Comment: It's not actually fullscreen. Just making the status bar translucent

Comment: @Anand Check my updated answer. You need to clear flags for the translucent status bar.

Comment: It did not work for me